# How to remove margin bottom from default Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, themes, margin

First i was trying to add a `ProgressBar` right to bottom of action bar, as google style.

So i made a lot of searches about how remove the vertical padding/margin of `ProgressBar` but unsuccessful, i notice that seems there's a margin bottom on action bar:

[image: image 1]

but on my xml the view has 0dp on top constraint:

[image: image 2]

another example (in this it's a little hard but you can see the difference betwen white color of background and the grey overlay color):

[image: image 3]

on more time 0dp constraint top:

[image: image 4]

I assume the problem with progressbar negative margin is this margin bottom, but as i extend the action bar `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` i have no access to her xml to define margins, how can i do this?

i've tried on my `AppTheme`:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>


<style name="ActionBarStyle">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:bottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pesquisar_root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
tools:context=".ui.pesquisar.PesquisarFragment">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerPesquisa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutNoItems"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/noItensDrawable"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error_accent_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/noItensLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        android:text="@string/nenhum_produto_encontrado_npor_favor_tente_novamente"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/noItensDrawable"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/noItensDrawable"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noItensDrawable" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/searchProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your xml layout?

Comment: @droidbaza edited with xml reffering to first print

Comment: that's the point! i use the default action bar from  `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` so i'm not able to change the margins

Comment: ok. try add this in your code getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); or in your style theme   <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>

Comment: @droidbaza don't worked